# How to send and receive array data from Visual Basic to PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, vb.net

I have a vb.net application where I am sending error string to a php page to process it.

Look at this:
[How to send and recieve data from Visual Basic to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37770767/how-to-send-and-recieve-data-from-visual-basic-to-php)

But now, I want to send and receive array data from Visual Basic to PHP.

Well, if the `errorString` is like this array:

```
Dim errorString As String = new String(2) {}
errorString(0) = "Hello"
errorString(1) = "World!" ,
```

how can I send this `errorString`?

Anyone help me!

Comment: what format is your PHP page expecting the POST data in? Is it JSON, or XML, or simple form data?

Comment: It's simple from data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're folllowing the example in the link you gave above, this should work:

```
Dim errorString = "errorString[0]=Hello&errorString[1]=World"
```

...

```
Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(errorString)
```

Obviously if you want to do this programatically, where you don't know the contents of the array in advance, then you might have to do a loop through the array to build up the string one field at a time.

On the PHP side, you should then be able to do (for example):

```
foreach ($_POST['errorString'] as $key => $value) {
echo $value . "<br />";
}
```

This will allow you to access all the fields in the errorString array.